# looping dates and checking quota per month

Tags: laravel

I have data for dates for 180 days, and each month has only 6 quotas. How to loop through these dates, and if in month A or B the quota is full, then skip to the next month?

```html
$available_date = $lists->groupBy('delivery_date_month');
            foreach ($available_date as $key => $total) {

                $kokoko = $total->countBy(function ($item) {
                    return $item['delivery_date'];
                });

                foreach ($kokoko as $keye => $value) {
                    if ($keye == $date) {
                        if (!in_array($keye, $exists)) {
                            array_push($exists, $date);
                            if ($value < $this->getQuotaStd()) {
                                $new_list_vip[] = array(
                                    'delivery_date'  => $keye,
                                    'total_delivery' => $this->getQuotaVip() - $value . ' VIP',
                                    'month_year'     => date('M Y', strtotime($keye)),
                                    'display_date'   => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($keye)),
                                    'quota_per_month' => $this->getQuotaVipPerMonth() - $total,
                                );
                            }

                            $found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            if (!$found) {
                $new_list_vip[] = array(
                    'delivery_date'  => $date,
                    'total_delivery' => $this->getQuotaVip() . ' VIP',
                    'month_year'     => date('M Y', strtotime($date)),
                    'display_date'   => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date)),
                    'quota_per_month' => $this->getQuotaVipPerMonth(),
                );
            }
```